# How to download multiple files from url to server using php

Tags: php

I am wanting to download the files from clickbank onto my server

```
<?php
    $url = "https://accounts.clickbank.com/feeds/marketplace_feed_v2.xml.zip";
    file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen($url, 'r'));
?>
```

i am only getting a dtd file and the xml file is not downloading, it should have two files one dtd and one xml

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a .zip-Archive this way:

```
if ($fp1 = fopen($url, 'rb')) 
{ 
   $tempname = './downloaded.zip'; 
   if ($fp2 = fopen($tempname, 'wb')) 
   { 
     fwrite($fp2, file_get_contents($file)); 
     fclose($fp2); 
   } 
   fclose($fp1); 
}
```